# Azure WebJobs SDK and Emulator - Triggers not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-sdk-.net

I'm attempting to update azure SDK from v1 to v3, and hook it up to the Azure Storage Emulator for testing; using console application and .NET Framework.

It doesn't appear to like any of the triggers that worked previously, the 'SomeFunction' in the error is a simple QueueTrigger with a timeout.

**Exception**: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException: 'Error indexing method '*.SomeFunction'

**Inner Exception**: InvalidOperationException: Storage account 'Storage' is not configured.

```
[Timeout("00:30:00")]
public static async Task SomeFunction([QueueTrigger("queue")] CloudQueueMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;" />
  <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  <add key="AzureQueueName" value="queue" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## 1. Use appSettings.json

Version 3 of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs is no longer configured with an `app.config` file, but with an `appSettings.json` file. Place it in the root of your app and make sure the "*Copy to output directory*" property of the *appSettings.json* file is set to either *Copy if newer* or *Copy always*, or add this to your `.csproj` file directly using *Always* or *PreserveNewest*:

```
<Project ...> 
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

## 2. appSettings.json content

Your `appSettings.json` file should have the Storage connection string:

#### in development

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

#### in production

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=key;..."
  }
}
```

See [this .NET Core 2.1 sample host application](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/v3.0.3/sample/SampleHost) for more info on configuring in version 3. Though it might be somewhat different than .NET Framework that you are using.

Comment: This solves my issue thanks, is the appSettings.json a .NET Core approach? Strange app.config has been removed.

Comment: This has to be the most helpful thing I've seen regarding configuring azure storage. how on earth did you stumble on this?

Comment: it helped a lot!